# Unity web gl game wont display loading screen and just is blank screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, manifest.json, webgl-extensions

I have been working on a game and trying to upload it to the chrome extension store. When i open it through the manifest or clicking on index.html file it shows a blank screen and does not load at all. There is a few errors about the build loader also for some reason unity isn't building with a unityProgress.js and I am pretty certain it is post to but I cant find anything about it online also none of the buttons work when I load a local host server.

and I here is the project files in the link (with manifest, background.js and everything else). [Click here to go to the project files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ovV8SK5aYjwLPlECuI7skNtQ4mdJFrGm?usp=sharing)

Comment: [-> Networking in WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html)

Comment: Also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: ok srry did not know that

Comment: and i still dont know how to fix it? @derHugo